# How can I use fade effect like a css transition to a image tag in SVG?

Tags: image, animation, svg

I have a svg image that is clipped by a polygon.
I have 5 images in total and I'm letting the image change every 3 seconds by JS.

It looks ok, but the image switches too fast and abruptly, so I want to use some fade effect on them when they switch.

Could anyone help me figure out how I can achieve this?
So far I've learned that css transition cannot be used for the svg attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300"
   style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" xml:space="preserve">
   <clipPath id="clip01">
      <polygon class="st0 line01"
         points="212.1,0.7 212.1,175.5 434.9,85.2" />
   </clipPath>
   <image xlink:href="img/bg_01.jpg" x="-100" y="0" width="1000"
      height="500" style="clip-path: url(#clip01);" opacity="1" />
</svg>


<script>
$(function () {
var i = 1;
function changeBG() {
document.querySelector("image").setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'img/bg_0' + i + '.jpg');
i++;
}
setInterval(changeBG, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it: In Javascript you change the opacity every 3 sec in my example and in CSS you have `transition:opacity 1s;`

```js
let theopacity = 1;
setInterval(function(){ 
theopacity = Math.abs(theopacity - 1) ;
img.style.opacity = theopacity;
}, 3000);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
image{
opacity:1;
transition:opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="170 0 300 175" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" xml:space="preserve">
   <clipPath id="clip01">
      <polygon class="st0 line01"
         points="212.1,0.7 212.1,175.5 434.9,85.2"/>
   </clipPath>
   <g style="clip-path: url(#clip01);">
   <image xlink:href="https://www.rocketgardens.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/edible-flower-planter-1000x500.jpg" x="-100" y="0" width="1000" height="500"  opacity="1">
   </image>
   <image id="img" xlink:href="https://images.discerningassets.com/image/upload/c_fit,h_1000,w_1000/c_fit,fl_relative,h_1.0,l_deco_watermark,o_40,w_1.0/v1522547348/Lilac-Blooms-Lavender_crpsoc.jpg" x="-100" y="0" width="1000" height="500"  opacity="1">
   </image>
   </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, enxaneta. I actually tried a different way I had found myself and it worked, but the way you suggested above worked perfect too. Thank you.

Comment: @gwen Even better add a plus for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did. The idea is somewhat similar to enxaneta's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <svg id="svg02" class="svg02" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 575.2 481.5" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" xml:space="preserve">

    <clipPath id="clip01">
        <polygon class="st0 line01" points="212.1,0.7 212.1,175.5 434.9,85.2    " />

    </clipPath>
    <image class="image_01" xlink:href="img/bg_01.jpg" x="-200" y="0" width="1000" height="500" style="clip-path: url(#clip01);" />
    <image class="image_02" xlink:href="img/bg_01.jpg" x="-200" y="0" width="1000" height="500" style="clip-path: url(#clip01);" />
</svg>

<script>
var imgChange = function() {
var i = 1;

function changeBackground() {
    $(".image_02")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn();

    if (i > 5) {
        i = 1;
    }

    document
        .querySelector(".image_01")
        .setAttributeNS(
            "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
            "xlink:href",
            "img/bg_0" + (i - 1) + ".jpg"
        );

    document
        .querySelector(".image_02")
        .setAttributeNS(
            "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
            "xlink:href",
            "img/bg_0" + i + ".jpg"
        );

    i++;
}
setInterval(changeBackground, 3000);
};

imgChange();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an [`<animate>`](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) tag:

> ```
> <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
> ```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" xml:space="preserve">
   <clipPath id="clip01">
      <polygon class="st0 line01"
         points="212.1,0.7 212.1,175.5 434.9,85.2"/>
   </clipPath>
   <image xlink:href="img/bg_01.jpg" x="-100" y="0" width="1000" height="500" style="clip-path: url(#clip01);" opacity="1"/>
   
   <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, zer00ne. I didn't realized that there's an animate tag for svg. It worked fine.